# Does Rust automatically dereference primitive type references?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and trying to learn how references work. In the following code when I want to do a calculation on `a1` which is `i32` I don't have to dereference it. But with `b1` which is a `Box`, I have to dereference it.

Actually both `let a2 = a1 * 2;` and `let a3 = *a1 * 2;` behave similarly. It looks like dereferencing in primitives is optional OR the compiler is implicitly doing that for us.

```
fn main(){
    let a = 5;
    let b = Box::new(10);
    let a1 = &a;
    let b1 = &b;

    println!("{} {}", a1, b1);

    let a2 = a1 * 2;
    let b2 = (**b1) * 10;
    let a3 = *a1 * 2;

    println!("{} {} {}", a2, a3, b2);

}
```

Can someone please explain this functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of the arithmetic operators in Rust are implemented for both primitive values and references to primitives on either side of the operator. For example, see the `Implementors` section of [`std::ops::Mul`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html), the trait that controls the overriding of the `*` operator.

You'll see something like:

```
impl Mul<i32> for i32
impl<'a> Mul<i32> for &'a i32
impl<'a> Mul<&'a i32> for i32
impl<'a, 'b> Mul<&'a i32> for &'b i32
```

and so on and so on.

In your example, `b1` has a type of `&Box<i32>` (the default integer type), and while `Box` implements many traits as a passthrough for its contained type (e.g. `impl<T: Read> Read for Box<T>`), the arithmetic operators are not among them. That is why you have to dereference the box.

Comment: Yes, unconstrained integer literals default to `i32`.