# About trait Index implement of Vector in Rust

Tags: rust

I check Index trait in doc and find return type of `index()` is `&T`.

Then I write this function to get value from vector:

```
fn get_value_test(a: usize, v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v[a]
}
```

My question is: why `v[a]` is `i32` but `&i32`? Because `i32` `...have a known size at compile time are stored entirely on the stack, so copies of the actual values are quick to make`? (from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html))

It looks like Rust have hidden rule to convert type in this situation?

Comment: Side note: [it is discouraged to accept `&Vec<_>` and the like as a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/1233251).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a small misguidance here. Although the method prototype for [`Index<Idx>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html) is `fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &T`, the syntactical operator `x[i]` *does* dereference the output from that `&T`:

> `container[index]` is actually syntactic sugar for `*container.index(index)` [...]. This allows nice things such as `let value = v[index]` if the type of `value` implements `Copy`.

So there you go. Your function is indeed returning a copy of the value from the vector, but not from an implicit conversion. If the original intent was to really retrieve a reference to that value, you would do `&x[i]`.

See also:

- [Meaning of the ampersand '&' and star '*' symbols in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335342/meaning-of-the-ampersand-and-star-symbols-in-rust)
- [Does Rust automatically dereference primitive type references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216530/does-rust-automatically-dereference-primitive-type-references)

Comment: Thank you. It is interesting to learn rust.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this allows `&x[i]` to reference the value in the vector, since otherwise it'd have to move the value out of the vector, and then take a reference to the moved value which would be unworkable.

Comment: @ccQpein: To be honest, this is a dirty hack really. The problem is that you would really like to be able to parameterize the `Output` associated type of `Index` by a lifetime, allowing the user to decide whether to return a reference or not, but this is not yet possible. Therefore, for ergonomics reasons, we have this weird hack in place. As you may have guessed, I am not a fan :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. I suppose you meant to ping @loganfsmyth?

Comment: @E_net4: No, I meant to ping the OP :) I don't find this hack "interesting", it's a wart to me.